# Table DB automatically fill

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table in mysql.

```
People {
  name
  country
  city
}
country{
  country_id (PK)
  country_name
}
city{
  country_id(FK)
  city_id(PK)
  city_name
}
```

Is it possible, when I only add attribute data "name" and "city" in the table people, mysql will automatically populate the "country" too, cause country_id linked between city and country ??

Comment: Perth,Scotland, Perth Australia which country wins?

Comment: And no mysql cannot do this automatically you would have to code for it probably using a trigger.

Comment: Your problem is interesting. But it's not a good idea to select key field based on Non-Key field. As mentioned by P.Salmon above there are huge possibilites of inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the case then you don't need the "country" field in the People table. What you need is a city_id(FK) as a Foreign Key, which will join to your City table, which will then join to your country table on country_id

```
People {
        name
        city_id(FK)
       }
```